# How to add two dataLabels to a bar chart using HightCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to show two labels on each bar, one inside the bar and the other on top of the bar. The inside representing the quantity and the upper representing the percentage of that value for the total.

[image]

```js
 dados = [
    {
                    name: "January",
                    y: 40,
                },
                {
                    name: "February",
                    y: 10,
                },
                {
                    name: "March",
                    y: 7,
                },
                {
                    name: "April",
                    y: 5,
                },
                {
                    name: "June",
                    y: 4,
                },
                {
                    name: "July",
                    y: 1,
                },
                {
                    name: "August",
                    y: 7,
                },
                {
                    name: "September",
                    y: 17,
                },
                {
                    name: "October",
                    y: 12,
                },
                {
                    name: "November",
                    y: 15,
                },
                {
                    name: "December",
                    y: 10,
                }
            ];
  //percentage code
    Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
        var total = 0
        for ( var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
        total += this[i][prop]
        }
        return total
    }

    var soma = dados.sum("y");
    var total = dados.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++){
        dados[i]['p'] = dados[i].y*100/soma;
    }
//
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Quantidade de fatos históricos por período'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Fatos históricos (quantidade)'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Quantidade em {point.name}: <b>{point.y} ({point.p:.2f} % )</b>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Population',
        data: dados,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
    
    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
                            <div id="container"></div>
                            <p class="highcharts-description">
                                
                            </p>
                        </figure>
```

I added a code that adds p (percentage) to the data, I also want to know if hightcharts already does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple data labels to a single point by defining them as an array:

```
dataLabels: [{
  ...
}, {
  ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5gL6paqr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels